# What does "in one form or another" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> In Italy bells stand for power and control. And bells, **in one form or another**, accompanied him throughout his life.

The [article](https://www.economist.com/news/obituary/21577350-giulio-andreotti-many-times-prime-minister-italy-died-may-6th-aged-94-giulio-andreotti) is talking about the prime minister of Italy. I am confused about the phrase "in one form or another", does it refer to "power and control"?

Comment: No, it refers to bells. It means there were often situations connected with bells in his life. The article then goes on to give you examples of how often bells popped up in his life.

Answer (score 2):

The expression *in one form or another* is a variation on the more common one [**in one way or another**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-way-or-another). So, the passage is saying that bells, in one way or another (in some way that is not stated), played a major part in his life. Maybe, he used bells as the doorbells for his door. Maybe, he had a bell hung up on the wall over his bed as a lucky charm. Maybe, he simply had bells as souvenirs in his house. Maybe, he worked as a production manager at a factory that manufactured bells. That's what it basically says.